# How to multiply all elements of two lists with each other in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am thinking how to multiply all elements of two list with each other. Then I want to put all results in `List3`. For example,

```
List1 = [1,3,5].
List2 = [2,6,7].
```

`List3`should contain [1x2, 1x6, 1x7, 3x2, 3x6, 3x7, 5x2, 5x6, 5x7].
In the end;

```
List3 = [2, 6, 7, 6, 18, 21, 10, 30, 35].
```

Is it possible to do that? How to do that? I couldn't find a right way.

Comment: Well, it is a Turing-complete language, so it must be possible

Comment: First, how could you multiply all elements of one list by one number ? Next, how could you use the former  code to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,First take a look on this question [executing operation for each list element in swi-prolog and others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7537804/992406) to know how to do `for-each` operation on `lists`.
Second, here is the code:

```
prod(X,[],[]).
prod(X,[HEAD|TAIL],L) :-  prod(X,TAIL,L1), W is X * HEAD, L = [W|L1].

prod2([],Y,[]).
prod2([HEAD|TAIL],Y,L) :- prod(HEAD,Y,L1), prod2(TAIL,Y,L2), append(L1,L2,L).
```

output:

```
?- prod2([1,3,5] ,[2,6,7],G).
G = [2, 6, 7, 6, 18, 21, 10, 30, 35] .
```

Comment: This solution is not tail-recursive, requires relatively costly calls to `append/3`, doesn't take advantage of the first-argument indexing found on most Prolog systems, and leaves spurious choice-points.

Comment: @PauloMoura: you are right, but most beginners prefer simple readable code more than complex one.

Comment: Hmm, it is a "correct" solution but as @PauloMoura has pointed out, it has a lot of deficiencies. I won't even go into coding guidelines (if you do program in Prolog, take a look [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899)). But since OP is probably not too interested in learning Prolog anyway, I guess taking your solution as "correct" does not do too much harm.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rather straight-forward solution using `library(lambda)`

```
product(Xs, Ys, Ps) :-
   maplist(Ys+\X^maplist({X,Ys}+\Y^YP^(YP=X*Y),Ys), Xs, PPs),
   append(PPs, Ps).
```

So we have an outer-loop for `Xs` and an inner loop for `Ys`.

```
?- product([1,2,3],[4,5,6],Ps).
   Ps = [1*4,1*5,1*6,2*4,2*5,2*6,3*4,3*5,3*6].
```

Replace `(YP=X*Y)` by `(YP is X*Y)` or `(YP #= X*Y)`. Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
prod(L1, L2, LP) :-
    bagof(P, X^Y^(member(X, L1), member(Y, L2), P is X * Y), LP).
```

Comment: "Why not": because it does not scale to constraints (in many implementations).

Comment: OK, I only SWI-Prolog !

Comment: In SWI, when replacing `is` by `#=`.  Your definition with `prod([X],[Y],Zs)` correctly succeeds with `Zs = [_G1], X*Y #= _G1`, but incorrectly fails for `prod([X,X],[Y],Zs)`. These kinds of subtle errors make debugging a nightmare.

Comment: A maybe more convincing example: `prod([1,1],[2],Zs)` correctly succeeds with `Zs = [2,2]`. But `prod([1,1],[Y],Zs), Y = 2` while logically equivalent, now fails, because the first goal fails.

Comment: When I posted my code, I must say that I didn't think of all these problems ! I often forget that in Prolog, arguments can be unified or not before the call of the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!** "Cross product"—shown here—is just one of **many applications**. Proceed like this:

```
:- meta_predicate xproduct(4,?,?,?).
xproduct(P_4,As) -->
   xproduct(P_4,As,As).

:- meta_predicate xproduct(4,?,?,?,?).
xproduct(P_4,As,Bs) -->
   xproduct_aux1(As,Bs,P_4).                % use 1st argument indexing for As

:- meta_predicate xproduct_aux1(?,?,4,?,?).
xproduct_aux1([]    ,_ , _ ) --> [].
xproduct_aux1([A|As],Bs,P_4) -->
   xproduct_aux2(Bs,[A|As],P_4).            % use 1st argument indexing for Bs

:- meta_predicate xproduct_aux2(?,?,4,?,?).
xproduct_aux2([],_,_) --> [].
xproduct_aux2([B|Bs],As,P_4) -->
   xproduct_(As,[B|Bs],P_4).

:- meta_predicate xproduct_(?,?,4,?,?).
xproduct_([],_,_) --> [].
xproduct_([A|As],Bs,P_4) -->
    xprod_(Bs,A,P_4),
    xproduct_(As,Bs,P_4).

:- meta_predicate xprod_(?,?,4,?,?).
xprod_([],_,_) --> [].
xprod_([B|Bs],A,P_4) -->
    call(P_4,A,B),
    xprod_(Bs,A,P_4).
```

Let's use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and [lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) to
run the query you provided in your question:

```
:- use_module([library(clpfd),library(lambda)]).

?- phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^[Z|Zs]^Zs^(Z #= X*Y),[1,3,5],[2,6,7]),Fs).
Fs = [2,6,7,6,18,21,10,30,35].
```

Above lambdas use [difference-lists](/questions/tagged/difference-lists) *explicitly*;
with `phrase//1` we can also use them *implicitly*!

```
?- phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^phrase(([Z],{Z #= X*Y})),[1,3,5],[2,6,7]),Fs).
Fs = [2,6,7,6,18,21,10,30,35].
```

[clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) enables us to do very general queries. Thanks to @PauloMoura for his suggestion! Look!

```
?- phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^phrase(([Z],{Z #= X*Y})),As,Bs),
          [2,6,7,6,18,21,10,30,35]),
   maplist(labeling([]),[As,Bs]).
  As = [-2,-6,-7,-6,-18,-21,-10,-30,-35], Bs = [-1]
; As = [ 2, 6, 7, 6, 18, 21, 10, 30, 35], Bs = [ 1]
; As = [-1,-3,-5],                        Bs = [-2,-6,-7]
; As = [ 1, 3, 5],                        Bs = [ 2, 6, 7]
; As = [-1],                              Bs = [-2,-6,-7,-6,-18,-21,-10,-30,-35]
; As = [ 1],                              Bs = [ 2, 6, 7, 6, 18, 21, 10, 30, 35]
; false.
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time for my question, and solution

Comment: It would be helpful to add a query example that would highlight the advantages of using CLP(FD) when compared with simpler solutions using only standard, basic, arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution not requiring any Prolog extensions (but, of course, loosing the potential benefits of using CLP(FD)) would be:

```
product(List1, List2, Product) :-
    % save a copy of the second list
    product(List1, List2, List2, Product).

product([], _, _, []).
product([X| Xs], List2, Rest2, Product) :-
    (   Rest2 == [] ->
        product(Xs, List2, List2, Product)
    ;   Rest2 = [Y| Ys],
        Z is X * Y,
        Product = [Z| Zs],
        product([X| Xs], List2, Ys, Zs)
    ).
```

This solution is tail-recursive and doesn't leave spurious choice-points.

Comment: The people helps who need helps, it will make a better world.  Thanks for attention